# CMake не может найти заголовочный файл

Tags: c++, cmake

Используем для проекта **GMP**. При сборке проекта **CMake** выкидывает мне следующее:

```
 fatal error: 'gmpxx.h' file not found
```

При этом `cpp -v` выводит:

```
 #include "..." search starts here:
 #include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 ...
 ...
```

А `gmpxx.h` и `gmp.h` есть и в `/usr/local/include` и в `/usr/local/Cellar`

Comment: Это выдает именно cmake? Не make (или что там у вас), не компилятор?

Comment: `make -V`, чтобы увидеть командную строку. Можете запустить ее отдельно, чтобы проверить.

Comment: Посмотрите в CMakeLists.txt проекта, который не собирается, функцию ``include_directories()``. По идее, в ней должен быть и путь, где лежит хедер. Попробуйте напечатать список каталогов, что-то вроде 
``get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(${dir})``

Comment: @VTT , ну, судя по всему, именно CMake, тк он используется как система сборки.